# Having trouble with assigning a value to textContent and toggling a class in JS

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am displaying quotes that are stored in a nested array.
When the user presses the next button I generate a random number and assign the contents of the random array index to the textContent of the heading and paragraph element. This works fine.

After I assign the value I am toggling a class that fades the text in.

For some reason, only every second quote fades in.

What should I be doing differently?

Note. quotes is a nested array of quotes.

```js
    const quotes = [
      ["quote 1", "author 1"],
      ["quote 2", "author 2"],
      ["quote 3", "author 3"],
      ["quote 4", "author 4"],
    ]
let quoteCount = 0;
let currentQuote = 0;
let quotesServed = [];

function getQuote(event) {
    let nextQuote = 0;
    let randomQuote = 0;
    let prevQuote = 0;
    let elementHeading = document.getElementById('quoteheadingID');
    let elementAuthor = document.getElementById('quoteauthorID');
    const whichButton = event.target.classList.contains('next')? "next" : "previous";
    
    if (whichButton==="next") {
        if (quoteCount === quotesServed.length) {
            do {
            randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);
            } while (randomQuote === quotesServed[quoteCount-1])
    
            
            elementHeading.textContent = quotes[randomQuote][0];
            elementHeading.classList.toggle('fadein');
            
            elementAuthor.textContent = quotes[randomQuote][1];
            elementAuthor.classList.toggle('fadein');
            
    
            quotesServed.push(randomQuote);
            quoteCount++;
            
            
        } else {
            if (quoteCount < quotes.length ) {
                nextQuote = quotesServed[quoteCount];
                
            
                elementHeading.textContent = quotes[nextQuote][0];
                elementHeading.classList.toggle('fadein');
                elementAuthor.textContent = quotes[nextQuote][1];
                elementAuthor.classList.toggle('fadein');
                quoteCount++;
            } 
        }

    } else if (whichButton==="previous") {
        if (quoteCount > 1) {
            quoteCount--;
            prevQuote = quotesServed[quoteCount-1];
            elementHeading.textContent = quotes[prevQuote][0];
            elementHeading.classList.toggle('fadein');
            elementAuthor.textContent = quotes[prevQuote][1];
            elementAuthor.classList.toggle('fadein');
            
        }
    }
    
}

    document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', getQuote);
    document.querySelector('.previous').addEventListener('click', getQuote);
```

```css
.fadein {
  animation: fadeIn linear 7s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quote_container">

  <figure class="quotefigure">
    <img class="quoteimage" src="./Resources/Images/flag.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
  </figure>
  <div class="quotetext_container">
    <h1 id="quoteheadingID" class="quoteheading fadein"></h1>
    <p id="quoteauthorID" class="quoteauthor fadein"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prevnext_container">
    <a href="#" class="previous">&#8249;</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">&#8250;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `quotes`, and where it has been defined? Currently it just pops up to the code from nowhere.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with relevant HTML and the relevant `quotesServed` object

Comment: @mplungjan I have added all of the script (except quote, which is a nested array) and the HTML for the image that contains the quote, the quoteheading, quoteauthor, and the prev and next buttons the user clicks.

Comment: @Teemu quotes = [["quote","author"],["quote, "author"],] it;s quite long so I did not include it. Everything is working fine - the only problem is toggling fadein. It is only working on every second quote when next or previous are clicked. I have updated the code snippet with the entire JS and the HTML too.

Comment: But we NEED quotes, just a small version.

Comment: I updated your code. I added two authors and a curly bracket

Comment: Also DRY - you need to have only one script for next and previous and change the direction

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for updating my code - it's my second post on here, I will make sure my next one is perfect. I can sort out the function with event and .this. Very good point, thank you!

Comment: @mplungjan I have refactored my code to only have one function. Any idea what's causing the toggle("fadein") to only apply to every second getQuote?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263034/383904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keyframes do not [restart after having been triggered](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

You need to re-insert the HTML that uses them

I shuffle the array instead of randomise when clicking

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array
}
const quotes = shuffleArray([
  ["quote 1", "author 1"],
  ["quote 2", "author 2"],
  ["quote 3", "author 3"],
  ["quote 4", "author 4"],
]);

const container = document.querySelector('.quote_container'),
  navContainer = document.querySelector('.prevnext_container');

let cnt = 0;
const navigate = e => {
  // restart animation
  const  textContainer = document.querySelector('.quotetext_container')
  const newContainer = textContainer.outerHTML
  textContainer.remove()
  navContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',newContainer);
  const elementHeading = document.getElementById('quoteheadingID'),
    elementAuthor = document.getElementById('quoteauthorID');
  // if called without an event we are loading the first entry
  let dir = 0; // handle first load
  // else use whatever was clicked
  if (e && e.target) dir = e.target.id === 'next' ? 1 : -1;
  cnt += dir
  // reset - here you can wrap if you want
  if (cnt < 0) cnt = 0;
  else if (cnt >= quotes.length - 1) cnt = quotes.length - 1;
  // get the author and quote
  const [q, a] = quotes[cnt];
  elementHeading.innerHTML = q;
  elementAuthor.innerHTML = a;

}

document.querySelector('.prevnext_container').addEventListener('click', navigate);
navigate()
```

```css
.fadein {
  animation: fadeIn linear 7s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quote_container">

  <figure class="quotefigure">
    <img class="quoteimage" src="./Resources/Images/flag.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
  </figure>
  <div class="quotetext_container fadein">
    <h1 id="quoteheadingID" class="quoteheading"></h1>
    <p id="quoteauthorID" class="quoteauthor"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prevnext_container">
    <a href="#" class="nav" id="previous">&#8249;</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav" id="next">&#8250;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That makes total sense

Comment: @mplungjan loops should never start at `-1` but at `0` it's way easier to reason about. Init, and only afterwards, on prev/next increment or decrement. Never let it go to -1

Comment: Ok, @RokoC.Buljan I fixed it better now

Answer (score 0):

After receiving some help and doing some more searching online I came across a more reliable method for resetting the animation thanks to an article on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Tips

```
function play(index) {
    const [q, a] = quotes[index];
    let elementHeading = document.getElementById('quoteheadingID');
    let elementAuthor = document.getElementById('quoteauthorID');
        
    document.querySelector(".quoteheading").className = "quoteheading";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
            elementHeading.textContent = q;
            document.querySelector(".quoteheading").className = "quoteheading fadein";
        });
    });

    document.querySelector(".quoteauthor").className = "quoteauthor";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
            elementAuthor.textContent = a;
            document.querySelector(".quoteauthor").className = "quoteauthor fadein";
        });
    });

    
}
```

Works perfectly