# Add Prev Next Controls to Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, controls, intervals

After toying about with timers and intervals I have come to a solution that works to my satisfaction.

See [relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayj95bx8/) or code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">irrelevant content</div>
```

javascript( with jQuery):

```
var post_array = [ "abc", "123", "xyz" ];
var class_array = [ "red", "blue", "green" ];

var interval = 2000;
var i = 0;
var max = post_array.length;
var id ="#foo";

$(id).html(post_array[0]);
$(id).removeClass().addClass(class_array[0]);

setInterval( function(){
    ++i;
    $(id).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(id).html(post_array[i%max]).fadeIn("slow");
    $(id).removeClass().addClass(class_array[i%max]);
  });
}, interval);
```

Now I wonder what the best way to add two side arrows that allow me to go back and fort would be.

should I have written the relevant code in a named function so I can call it and pass an index parameter when the button is pressed? ( how do i act on the same index variable in that case? )
What's the best practice for button overlays?

Help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way. A JS Carousel code should be reusable - and not force you to copy/paste code for eventual N carousels. Creating an autoplay means you need also a *hover-to-pause* `stop` Method. On mouseenter you need to stop it, on mouseleave you need to trigger again a `play` method... etc etc etc. That way when you click PREV/NEXT you won't get unwanted glitches and a terribly broken UX.

Comment: https://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Comment: This seems a bit besides the point, maybe open your own thread to discuss that there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Carousels should be modular, reusable and extendable. Don't copy paste JS code when in need to add another Carousel into your DOM.
- In order to create PREV / NEXT buttons you'll also need a method to stop your interval: `stop`
- When you hover over your Carousel, you'll need to pause the *autoplay* to prevent a really bad User Experience (UX)
- Don't animate using jQuery. Animate by simply assigning an `is-active` class to the current index slide, and use CSS to do whatever you want with that class.
- **Use a variable `index` (start with 0) to keep track of the current slide index**
- [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Aim to create a class instance using the sugary `class` or the proper `prototype` syntax - that can be used like:

```js
const myCarousel = new Carousel({
  target: "#carousel-one",
  slides: [
    {
      title: "This is slide one",
      image: "images/one.jpg"
    },
    {
      title: "This is slide two! Yey.",
      image: "images/two.jpg"
    }
  ]
});
```

So basically, you'll need a **constructor** that has those methods:

| Method | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `anim()` | Fix index if exceeds slides or is negative and **animate to new index** |
| `prev()` | **Decrement index** and trigger `anim()` |
| `next()` | **Increment index** and trigger `anim()` |
| `stop()` | Clear loop interval (On mouseenter) |
| `play()` | Start loop (Triggers `next()` every `pause` milliseconds) |

### Simple JavaScript carousel example

```js
class Carousel {
  constructor(options) {

    Object.assign(this, {
      slides: [],
      index: 0,
      pause: 4000, // Pause between slides
      EL: document.querySelector(options.target || "#Carousel"),
      autoplay: true,
    }, options);

    this.total = this.slides.length;
    this.EL_area = this.EL.querySelector(".Carousel-area");
    this.EL_prev = this.EL.querySelector(".Carousel-prev");
    this.EL_next = this.EL.querySelector(".Carousel-next");

    const NewEL = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

    // Preload images
    this.ELs_items = this.slides.reduce((DF, item) => {
      const EL_slide = NewEL("div", {
        className: "Carousel-slide"
      });
      const EL_image = NewEL("img", {
        className: "Carousel-image",
        src: item.image,
        alt: item.title
      });
      const EL_content = NewEL("div", {
        className: "Carousel-title",
        textContent: item.title
      });
      EL_slide.append(EL_image, EL_content);
      DF.push(EL_slide);
      return DF;
    }, []);
    this.EL_area.append(...this.ELs_items);

    // Events
    this.EL_prev.addEventListener("click", () => this.prev());
    this.EL_next.addEventListener("click", () => this.next());
    this.EL.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => this.stop());
    this.EL.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => this.play());

    // Init
    this.anim();
    this.play();
  }

  // Methods:

  anim() {
    this.index = this.index < 0 ? this.total - 1 : this.index >= this.total ? 0 : this.index;
    this.ELs_items.forEach((EL, i) => EL.classList.toggle("is-active", i === this.index));
  }

  prev() {
    this.index -= 1;
    this.anim();
  }

  next() {
    this.index += 1;
    this.anim();
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.itv);
  }

  play() {
    if (this.autoplay) this.itv = setInterval(() => this.next(), this.pause);
  }
}


// Use like:
new Carousel({
  target: "#carousel-one",
  slides: [{
      title: "We're part of nature",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/10/400/300"
    },
    {
      title: "Remember to read and learn",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/24/400/300"
    },
    {
      title: "Up for a coffee?",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/id/30/400/300"
    },
  ]
});
```

```css
/* CAROUSEL */

.Carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.Carousel-slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s; /* DESIRED SLIDE TRANSITIONS */
  opacity: 0;               /* INACTIVE SLIDE*/
}

.Carousel-slide.is-active { /* ACTIVE SLIDE! */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Carousel-prev,
.Carousel-next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  user-select: none; /* Prevent highlight */
}

.Carousel-prev {
  left: 1em;
}
.Carousel-next{
  right: 1em;
}

.Carousel-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Carousel-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="Carousel" id="carousel-one">
  <div class="Carousel-area"></div>
  <button class="Carousel-prev" type="button" aria-label="Previous slide">&larr;</button>
  <button class="Carousel-next" type="button" aria-label="Next slide">&rarr;</button>
  <div class="Carousel-desc"></div>
</div>
```

With the above code you can have an unlimited number of carousels on a single page given every one has a different `target` ID.

---

PS: Alternatively, if your code keeps track of the *direction* for the prev / next, the logic to increment/decrement/loopback the **current index** can be also written as (pseudocode ahead!):

```js
C = (is_next ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? T-1 : C%T;
```

where `C` is the **current** index, `T` is the **total** number of slides, and `is_next` is a boolean that is `true` when the direction is *Next*.

Comment: I can see I have created some confusion with my improper usage of the word carousel. No need for images.

Just to clarify the code above is just a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the core mechanism.

I'm actually generating the content in php pulling wordpress custom posts and displaying them in a loop on the front page of this minimal artsy website.  jQuery is already in the mix, might as well make my life easier and use it to keep my code sub-billion lines.

Comment: @jmazzo Well, don't use the images than. (Remove all the codes that use the var `EL_image`) Also, even if I rewrote the above code into jQuery it would have almost the same number of lines. At this point it just depends how well you know JS

Comment: @jmazzo i.e: https://jsfiddle.net/3tv9nqyz/ - took ~20 seconds to remove the unnecessary code.

Comment: I realize that I was just clarifying, my approach was just get it working quick, this is great, thanks.