# why left property not working correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, carousel

I am planning to make below carousel  example my own with same logic.But I am facing one issue on setting left property.
**demo**
https://3dedy.csb.app/

1. Above example is infinite loop example.when user navigate to last slide .it show first slide
2. What I understand from example .When user on last slide .it `set first Item the left property` and show the first slide when user click on next button

**I used the same logic.**

I also set the left property when user is on last slide .But In my case I am not able to display first slide

May be I am doing something wrong
here is my code

```
 nextSlide() {
        const t       = this;
        const opts    = t.options;
        let nextSlide = t.activeSlide + 1;

        if ((t.activeSlide >= t.slidesLength) && !t.isEnabledOption('loop')) {
            t._paused = true;

            return;
        }

        if (nextSlide > t.slidesLength) {
            //
            console.log(t);
            t._slides[0].style.left = `${100*t._slides.length}%`
           // nextSlide = 1;
        }
```

whole code
https://plnkr.co/edit/PWJl4cELopwUaOL2?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: `let nextSlide = t.activeSlide + 1;` is complettely unnecessary. You already have `t.activeSlide` Use it! `if (t.activeSlide >= t.slidesLength) {` Also, don't camouflage unnecessarily `this` into `t`

Comment: You could use this answer as a great starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263034/383904 The logic goes like: `C = (is_next ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? T-1 : C%T;` and all you need is to than animate like: `100 * C %` All inside a single `anim()` function, method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for a carousel is quite straightforward:

```js
C = (is_next ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? T-1 : C%T;
```

where C is the current index and `T` is the total length of slides.

The basic animation and prev/next methods:

```js
  anim() {
    this.index = this.index < 0 ? this.total - 1 : this.index >= this.total ? 0 : this.index;
    this.EL.style.transform = `translateX(-${100 * this.index}%)`;
  }

  prev() {
    this.index -= 1;
    this.anim();
  }

  next() {
    this.index += 1;
    this.anim();
  }
```

More info can be found on [this SO answer (*Add Prev Next Controls to Carousel*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263034/383904)

Comment: thanks @roko if possible can you share my codesandbox

Comment: @user5711656 I think my code is far more simplistic than yours, therefore you should have less problems to implement the logic from this demo: https://jsbin.com/yecafijona/edit?html,css,js,output into your own code. Take a look at the nifty simple `anim, prev, next, stop, play` methods and you should get a grasp.

Comment: ok thanks .. np will check actually in my code everything is working like `touch handler`, navigation , dots functionality .. only left was infinite