# How can I make a product slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I want to create a javascript product slider that moves 150px every 5s and returns to the first slide when the slider is finished.
like this picture: https://magerta.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/WordPress-WooCommerce-Product-Slider-Plugins-Cover.jpg

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="slider-container best-Books">
            <div id="right-arrow" class="arrow">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            </div>
            <section class="slider">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons ">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h5>آسمان خراش</h5>
                        <p><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i></p>
                        <h6>نویسنده</h6>
                        <p>150 تومان<span>200 تومان</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div id="left-arrow" class="arrow">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-left    "></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
let thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".best-Books .slider .thumbnail");
let slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
let prev = document.querySelector("#left-arrow");
let next = document.querySelector("#right-arrow");
let maxSlide = slider.scrollWidth;


const maxScrollLeft = slider.scrollWidth - slider.clientWidth;

console.log(maxScrollLeft , slider.scrollLeft);
function autoPlay() {
  if(slider.scrollLeft > (maxScrollLeft - 1)){
    slider.scrollLeft -= maxScrollLeft;
  }
  else{
    slider.scrollLeft += 70;
  }
}

 prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slider.scrollLeft -= 100;
});
next.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slider.scrollLeft += 300;
});
let play = setInterval(autoPlay, 50);
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnail.length; i++) {
  thumbnail[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    clearInterval(play);
  });
  thumbnail[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    return (play = setInterval(autoPlay, 50));
  });
}
```

I made this myself, but where I had a problem was the slider repetition part.

Comment: Provide a minimum required source code first or look here about how to properly ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @amin your question is unclear please provide some reference to what exactly you want to achieve!

Comment: @amin please provide HTML code also

Comment: Don't you think 50ms is too fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72690608/383904 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68263034/383904 and many other...